# Do i need to install android NDK manually even after installing android NDK using SDK

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, bundle, android-sdk-tools

When i try to use "ndk-build" i get following error

> C:\Users\mack\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication>ndk-build 'ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Well after some research i found that ndk is not included in path folder of environment variables. Now when i check via SDK i can clearly see that i have checked and installed android NDK using the SDK of android studio, the path of which is

> C:\Users\mack\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle

and i even added this path to environment variables but no use. I am new to android so please pardon me if i am asking a dumb question. But its got me totally confused from like past couple of days.

Do i need to download and install android NDK manually from the [link](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download) below and install it and then add it to environment variables-path?

I have also included the snapshotot folder contents from NDK installed using android SDK
[image: Android NDK folder snapshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i can see from your error is that the PATH to the ndk-build may not be correct or that you do not have a runnable ndk-build file.

Are you sure that ndk-build.cmd is located inside of *C:\Users\mack\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle*?

A solution to this can be to download the Windows 32-bit NDK package from [Android NDK Download](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download) where the ndk-build file is runnable. And add the path to this folder to the

Comment: No there is no ndk-build.bat file in ndk-bundle folder. N path is correct. I guess I am going to do the second one. Download n install ndk manually n give path to that.

Comment: It should be `ndk-build.cmd` *NOT* `.bat`, also you should only add `C:\Users\mack\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle` to your `PATH` variable in windows (in "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path")

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved. i downloaded the ndk and manually installed it and added to environment variables, and its working smoothly. Thanks everyone :-)